# azure databricks workspace ls from conda environment

Tags: azure-functions, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-cloud-services

Hi I am trying to list the notebooks from my local windows machine using git bash. I have configured the databricks-cli and I can list the workspace.

```
$databricks workspace ls
dev
prod
```

I can also see what is inside dev folder.

```
$databricks workspace ls "//dev"
feature
hotfix
```

But When I try to see what is inside feature, I am receiving the below error.

```
$databricks workspace ls "//dev//feature"
Error: b'{"error_code":"RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"Path (//dev//feature) doesn\'t exist."}'
```

I don't get how to mention the subfolder. Could someone please help to resolve this?

Comment: Please try to run the command line in windows CMD, it seams that git bash cannot recogizne the path.

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-cli/issues/98) with Git Bash, I would suggest you to use command prompt (CMD) to see subfolders.

> Command prompt (CMD): `databricks workspace ls /DatabricksLab/DBLABS`

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.